# Invoking powershell script within c# that calls another powershell script is throwing an UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, powershell, runspace

The function below works well for my test

```
    private static void RunScript(string scriptText)
    {
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runspace.Open();
        Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
        pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText);
        pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");
        Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
        runspace.Close();
    }
```

I call this function like so

```
RunScript(File.ReadAllText("test.ps1"));
```

All is good. Now I have modified test.ps1 to call other powershell script.

But now I get an exception when I run this.

```
UnauthorizedAccessException: cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see 
about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
```

I'm guessing I need to set execution policy to "bypass". How can I set this?

Also is there a way to provide the powershell script filename into the Pipeline object instead of the contents of the script file?

Comment: `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy ByPass`

Comment: Why are you calling a PowerShell script from C# rather than native functions?

Comment: It to do with the solution running external powershell scripts for others to extend the functionality.

Comment: I know the command in calling powershell but I am asking about how can I specify that via the c# powershell APIs?

Answer (score 0):

OK after experimenting, figured out I can simply call my function multiple times. Once to set the policy and next time to call any scripts. The policy seems like it is set after just one call.

```
RunScript("Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy ByPass");
RunScript(File.ReadAllText("test.ps1"));

private static void RunScript(string scriptText)
{
    Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
    runspace.Open();
    Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
    pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText);
    pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");
    Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
    runspace.Close();
}
```

You can also queue commands i.e

```
private static void RunScript(string scriptText)
{
    Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
    runspace.Open();
    Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
    pipeline.Commands.AddScript("Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy ByPass");
    pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText);
    pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");
    Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
    runspace.Close();
}
```